# NodeJS NPM error

Tags: node.js, npm

I get an issue when I try to create a [Microscope](http://www.microscopejs.com) project (NodeJS Framework).

```
env: node\r: No such file or directory
```

When I try to create an Express app, everything works ! I don't understand why it doesn't work with Microscope.

My Node.js version : v0.10.24

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: It looks like you have a Windows-style newline somewhere where you shouldn't.

Comment: Ok and what I have to do?

Comment: Can you please brief more what exactly is the error and what have you tried?

Comment: I just executed the "microscope create appname" command and I got this error... If I execute "express test", it works ! But not with Microscope...